# How do you access the rails 2 flash[] hash in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Ok, I'm sure there is something simple that I'm missing here, but I can't quite seem to find the answer.

I have a modal that I updates both via normal HTTP request and now I'm adding some unobtrusive AJAX with jQuery to process the same request.

After the controller action I have user messages delivered in the flash[] hash (IE flash[:errors], flash[:message]) This is then displayed in on the redirect to page.

My question is:  How do I access this flash hash in my respond to .js file? What I want to do is something like:

```
$("#message").append(ADD FLASH MESSAGE HERE || render a message partial)
```

Comment: Hi Mike, it's generally considered good form to "accept" an answer that solved your problem. You can do that by clicking on the "tick" to the left of the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your jquery code can be treated just like any other (html) part of the partial template. So for your example, you should be able to use:

```
$("#message").append('<%= flash[:error] || render(:partial => :my_msg_partial) %>')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like `flash.to_json`